# Use of scipy.interpolate.griddata for interpolation of data of multiple dimensions from xarray

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, python-xarray

I have a rainfall data as xarray `DataSet` named `ds` of three dimensions `longitude`, `latitude` and `time`:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (latitude: 691, longitude: 886, time: 1)
Coordinates:
  * longitude  (longitude) float64 112.0 112.0 112.1 112.1 ... 156.2 156.2 156.3
  * latitude   (latitude) float64 -9.975 -10.03 -10.08 ... -44.42 -44.47 -44.52
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 1980-01-03
Data variables:
    RAIN       (time, latitude, longitude) float64 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

I would like to interpolate the rainfall values against another sets of longitudes and latitudes: `EXAMPLE_FFDI_LON_XR_DA` and `EXAMPLE_FFDI_LAT_XR_DA`. They have completely different values than the longitudes and latitudes of `ds`.

EXAMPLE_FFDI_LON_XR_DA:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'longitude' (longitude: 193)>
array([140.8    , 140.84792, ... ...], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 140.8 140.84792 140.89584 ... 149.95209 150.0
Attributes:
    latIntersect:         0.0
    lonCentre:            145.4
    units:                degrees_east
    projectionType:       MERCATOR
    _CoordinateAxisType:  Lon
```

EXAMPLE_FFDI_LAT_XR_DA:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'latitude' (latitude: 106)>
array([-39.2     , -39.149525, ... ...], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
  * latitude  (latitude) float32 -39.2 -39.149525 -39.09905 ... -33.950478 -33.9
Attributes:
    latIntersect:         0.0
    lonCentre:            145.4
    units:                degrees_north
    projectionType:       MERCATOR
    _CoordinateAxisType:  Lat
```

I thought of using xarray `xarray.DataArray.interp` function but this only supports the `nearest` method. I am new to scipy but thought it would better suit my need to interpolate using the scipy library `scipy.interpolate.griddata` function. How can I go about using this function with my data? A working example would be helpful.

Comment: It's worth checking out [`verde`](https://www.fatiando.org/verde/latest/) for gridding.

Comment: Did you specify the `method` param as [documented](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/interpolation.html)?

Comment: To provide yet another option, `xarray-extras` has [interpolation](https://xarray-extras.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/interpolate.html) too.

Comment: @Acumenus, Yes I did. But the `interp` function seems to only support method=`nearest`. This has given out discrepancies. I would like to use some smoother interpolation methods.

Comment: @alextc You should be able to use other interpolation functions from within xarray if you first install scipy. I haven't done it but it should be possible aa documented in the xarray docs.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry it only supports methods of `nearest` and `linear` for multiple dimensions. When I tried 'ds_interp = ds.interp(longitude=EXAMPLE_FFDI_LON_XR_DA, latitude=EXAMPLE_FFDI_LAT_XR_DA, method='cubic')' gave me `ValueError: cubic is not a valid interpolator for interpolating over multiple dimensions.`

Comment: You're doing this for each timestep separately then?

Comment: @Marc. Yes I can do this for each timestamp separately. This really doesn't matter. The key thing is to get scipy.interpolate.griddata working with the DataArray objects. I am still struggling with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure it's possible to have scipy interact with the DataArray objects as you have them now. What you can do is the following:

```
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import xarray
import numpy as np
# construct a dummy df like you have
values = np.random.rand(10, 30, 30) * 100
df = xarray.DataArray(values, [('time', range(10)), ('latitude', range(30)), ('longitude', range(30))])
# extract the values from the array
latitude = df['latitude'].values
longitude = df['longitude'].values
length_values = len(latitude) * len(longitude)

# create grid
x_grid, y_grid = np.meshgrid(latitude, longitude)
points = np.empty((length_values, 2))
points[:, 0] = x_grid.flatten()
points[:, 1] = y_grid.flatten()

# select a single timestep in which to interpolate the data
rain_at_locations = df.where(df.time == 3, drop=True)
values = np.array(rain_at_locations.values.flatten())

#your test locations
EXAMPLE_FFDI_LAT_XR_DA = range(5, 15) # extract these from you arrays
EXAMPLE_FFDI_LON_XR_DA = range(20, 30)
grid_x, grid_y = np.meshgrid(EXAMPLE_FFDI_LAT_XR_DA, EXAMPLE_FFDI_LON_XR_DA)

interpolated_values = griddata(points, values, (grid_x, grid_y), method='cubic')
```

These values can then be resupplied to a data array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am glad this helps. However, my question is if `df = xarray.DataArray(values, [('latitude', range(30)), ('longitude', range(30)), ('time', range(10))])` shouldn't be `df = xarray.DataArray(values, [('time', range(10)), ('latitude', range(30)), ('longitude', range(30))])`? Because the dimension of my original data has the DataArray of `<xarray.DataArray 'RAIN' (time: 1, latitude: 691, longitude: 886)>`

Comment: Owh sure, I don't see how that changes the solution significantly but I changed it to your DataArray order ;)

Comment: Thanks! I think this should be `x_grid, y_grid = np.meshgrid(longitude, latitude)` and `np.meshgrid(EXAMPLE_FFDI_LON_XR_DA, EXAMPLE_FFDI_LAT_XR_DA)` to create the grids.